# Coldfusion Error: cannot find file /CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm

Tags: apache, coldfusion, document-root

Right, I know you can google this question and get lots of answers on it, but none of them seem to work for me.

I've got a brand new RHEL5 server, with the latest LAMP installation on it, and I've just installed Coldfusion 9.

When I visit my site, i get the Coldfusion error saying

```
File not found: /index.cfm
```

If I navigate to a html or php page it's fine, they server properly. And the error I'm getting is the blue/grey coldfusion one, so the coldfusion server is working.

And I've narrowed the problem down to this...

**/var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/index.cfm** - this gets served

but my site root is really

**/var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs/index.cfm** - coldfusion cannot see this file!

I found this

**/var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/index.cfm**

in the cfserver.log. But I can't find anywhere that references **"/var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/"** as the root.

jrun-web.xml has a system path set to **/var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs**, and inside **"bin/coldfusion"** the DOCROOT is set to **"/var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs"**

This is a section of the httpd.include file:

```
# ATTENTION!
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE OR ANY PART OF IT. THIS CAN RESULT IN IMPROPER PLESK
# FUNCTIONING OR FAILURE, CAUSE DAMAGE AND LOSS OF DATA. IF YOU REQUIRE CUSTOM
# MODIFICATIONS TO BE APPLIED TO THE CONFIGURATION, PLEASE, PERFORM THEM IN THE
# FOLLOWING FILE(S):
# /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/conf/vhost.conf
# /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/subdomains/<subdomain-name>/conf/vhost.conf

<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName   site.co.uk:80
    ServerAlias  www.site.co.uk
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAdmin  "admin@site.co.uk"
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs
    CustomLog  /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/statistics/logs/access_log plesklog
    ErrorLog  /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/statistics/logs/error_log
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/web_users
</IfModule>
    Alias  /plesk-stat /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/statistics/
    <Location  /plesk-stat/>
        Options +Indexes
    </Location>
    <Location  /plesk-stat/logs/>
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
    Alias  /webstat /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/statistics/webstat
    Alias  /webstat-ssl /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/statistics/webstat-ssl
    Alias  /ftpstat /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/statistics/ftpstat
    Alias  /anon_ftpstat /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/statistics/anon_ftpstat
    Alias  /awstats-icon /var/www/html/awstats/icon
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        SSLEngine off
    </IfModule>
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs>
        <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
            php_admin_flag engine on
            php_admin_flag safe_mode off
            php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs:/tmp"
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            php_admin_flag engine on
            php_admin_flag safe_mode off
            php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs:/tmp"
        </IfModule>
        Options -Includes -ExecCGI
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/web_users>
        <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
            php_admin_flag engine off
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            php_admin_flag engine off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs/CFIDE">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName " "
        AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/pd/d..httpdocs@CFIDE
        require  valid-user
    </Directory>
    ... 
    Omitting other directory tags 
    ...
    Include /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/conf/vhost.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post a complete VirtualServer entry for your site please.  Change the names to protect the innocent, but don't add anything or take anything away.

Comment: Do you mean the <VirtualHost></VirtualHost> section of the httpd.include file?

Comment: Yes please.  Also, what version of ColdFusion Server are you running? Standard or Enterprise? If enterprise which install did you do? Standard or Multiserver?  How did you hook apache to ColdFusion?  When you did the installation were you asked for a context root?  If you were, what did you enter?  Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: We're running the CF9 Standard 30 Day Trial.
I ran the install bin, and followed the step by step instructions. 

I gave the installation the /etc/init.d/httpd paths, and when it asked for the web root to place CFIDE I gave it /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs.

Also, the httpd.include file is 250 lines long, as it's got hundreds of <Directory> tags in it, so I will omit those, but I can't see them being any help, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Comcar - question, so both the PHP and cfm is place in same folder?

Comment: Most of our pages our CFM, some are PHP, and yes they sit side by side in the same directory structure

Comment: Are you trying to get to www.site.co.uk/index.cfm or www.site.co.uk/CFIDE/Administrator/index.cfm?

Comment: Well I want both to work, but I've not yet been to www.site.co.uk/CFIDE/Administrator/index.cfm, so I need to go there first to set my DataSources

Comment: Do you have a "JRunConfig Bootstrap 127.0.0.1:51000" somewhere your apache config?

Comment: Does the physical path "/var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs/CFIDE" exist and do you get the user auth prompt when you try to access site.co.uk/CFIDE?

Comment: I have no idea where to look for this: "JRunConfig Bootstrap 127.0.0.1:51000"

And yes that directory does exist, I can get there through putty and view the source code of the CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm

I've got a .htaccess file on the administrator folder, I have to put in a user name and password that apache wants, then once through there I get the Coldfusion "file not found" error

Comment: The JRunConfig settings should be somewhere in the httpd config for apache. Have you tried accessing the ColdFusion admin without the user restriction? or have you tried http://localhost:8300/CFIDE/administrator ?

Comment: As a suggestion in future : On a *nix machine don't use a LAMP install "blob".  Install Apache, PHP and MySQL separately. It really isn't that complicated. Also, I always recommend installing ColdFusion Server, what ever the version, as standalone without connecting it to your webserver. Again, its pretty easy to manually connect apache to ColdFusion or use the wsconfig utility to help you connect once you're sure that its all up and running correctly.

Comment: I have this line in my httpd.conf : JRunConfig Bootstrap 127.0.0.1:51800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it, the problem was the RUNTIME_USER variable was set in various places to "nobody".

I managed to solve the problem thanks to this blog entry

http://nzflew.blogspot.com/2009/04/changing-user-of-coldfusion-on-linux.html

The "nobody" user didn't have access rights to view the files. I too had made the mistake of installing with the default "nobody" user name.

Thanks for all your help anyway.

Comment: ah yes. That would make things awkward. I've been bitten by this in the past, so I always create a "coldfusion" user to run the servers. You should mark this as the answer. ;)

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise I could click the tick to mark it as answered. I just assumed I couldn't answer my own question. 

Any way thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in a windows environment CF8/Apache2.2.  Just changed the apache and CF Application services to run using the same user acct.  Fixed it for me!

Comment: Good stuff, sounds pretty much like the Windows equivalent

Answer (score 0):

In your apache `vhosts.conf` file, for the `VirtualHost` entry of the site in question, you need something like this:

```
<VirtualHost some.ip.address:80>
ServerName    www.yoursite.com
DocumentRoot  /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs
...other stuff...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That's already there.

site.co.uk/index.html servers fine
site.co.uk/index.cfm fails

Apache is working fine, it's just the Coldfusion Server that can't see the files

Comment: Can you post the relevant portions of the file?

Comment: I've added them to the original post

Answer (score 0):

Going back to the start again. You said :

> And I've narrowed the problem down to
>   this...
>   /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/index.cfm -
>   this gets served
>
> but my site root is really
>
> /var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs/index.cfm
>   - coldfusion cannot see this file!

This suggests that something in your main config or your vhost config is either messing with your document path or your vhost config is not being triggered and you are dropping through to a default server config that points at /site.co.uk instead of /site.co.uk/httpdocs

The former is possibly a rewrite rule somewhere. 
The latter could be almost anything.  Although I did just notice that you have an include of a vhost.conf in the foot of your VirtualHost config block.

A suggestion would be to cut your config back to the absolute bare minimum eg. back to only serving html files with no hooks for php, coldfusion and all the other stuff that is in there and slowly put small elements back in when you've confirmed that the vhost is actually being picked up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply adding both an alias for the CFIDE directory and a DirectoryIndex directive:

```
Alias /CFIDE /{PATHTOTHEWEBROOT}/CFIDE

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php **index.cfm**
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem of running Coldfusion as a user? If the user's permissions are restricted, what is the issue?

Comment: Well it's just a matter of permissions really ... 

Debian Docs ... 

 "daemon: Some unprivileged daemons that need to write to files on disk run as daemon.daemon (e.g., portmap, atd, probably others). Daemons that don't need to own any files can run as nobody.nogroup instead, and more complex or security conscious daemons run as dedicated users. The daemon user is also handy for locally installed daemons. "

Comment: To add to this ... it's just as easy to chgrp ~/www to nobody to allow ColdFusion to run on VPS flavors like cPanel or Plesk ... I'm running CF on several sites on different user accounts on cPanel and it runs fine this way ...

Comment: I've edited my original statement regarding the CF user account as it wasn't accurate for all linux setups ...